# Am trying to find price of a particular route basing on the distance but whenever i put the places, the if loop returns the else not the price

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

```
//main.js
    //set map options
    var myLatLng = { lat: 51.5, lng: -0.1 };
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatLng,
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };

    //create map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

    //create a DirectionsService object to use the route method and get a result for our request
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    //create a DirectionsRenderer object which we will use to display the route
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    //bind the DirectionsRenderer to the map
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


    //define calcRoute function
    function calcRoute() {
        //create request

        var request = {
            origin: document.getElementById("source").value,

            destination: document.getElementById("destination").value,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING, //WALKING, BYCYCLING, TRANSIT
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
        }

        //pass the request to the route method
        directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                //Get distance and time
                var distance = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
                $("#output").html("<div class='alert-info'>From: " + document.getElementById("source").value + ".<br />To: " + document.getElementById("destination").value + ".<br /> Driving distance: " + result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text + ".<br />Duration: " + result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text + ".</div>");

                //START CALCULATING PRICE
                if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 20 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 1  ){
                        document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "30000";
                    }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 20 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 2  ) {
                        document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "50000";
                    }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 20 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 3  ) {
                        document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "50000";
                    }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 20 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 4  ) {
                        document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "100000";
                    }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 20 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 5  ) {
                        document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "50000";
                    }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 20 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 6  ) {
                        document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "100000";            
                    }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 20 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 7  ) {
                        document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "200000";
                    //END OF ZONE A
                 }
                 else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 21 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 30 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 1  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "70000";
                 }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 21 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 30 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 2  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "100000";
                 }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 21 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 30 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 3  ) {
                         document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "100000";
                 }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 21 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 30 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 4  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "150000";
                 }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 21 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 30 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 5  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "90000";
                 }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 21 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 30 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 6  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "120000";
                 }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 21 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 30 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 7  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "200000";
                 } //END OF ZONE B
                else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 31 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 40 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 1 ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "100000";
               }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 31 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 40 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 2 ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "150000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 31 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 40 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 3  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "150000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 31 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 40 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 4  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "250000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 31 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 40 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 5  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "170000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 31 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 40 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 6  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "250000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 31 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 40 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 7  ) {
                   document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "300000";
                } //END OF ZONE C
                else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 41 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 50 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 1 ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "130000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 41 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 50 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 2 ) {
                   document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "200000";
               }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 41 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 50 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 3  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "200000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 41 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 50 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 4  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "300000";
               }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 41 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 50 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 5  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "200000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 41 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 50 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 6  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "300000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 41 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 50 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 7  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "330000";
                }//END OF ZONE D
                else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 51 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 60 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 1 ) {
                   document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "160000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 51 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 60 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 2 ) {
                   document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "200000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 51 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 60 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 3  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "200000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 51 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 60 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 4  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "300000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 51 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 60 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 5  ) {
                   document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "200000";
               }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 51 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 60 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 6  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "300000";
                }else if(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value >= 51 && result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value <= 60 && document.getElementById("carclass").value == 7  ) {
                    document.getElementById("fareairport").value = "330000";
                }
                //END OF ZONE E
                else{

                    alert(document.getElementById("carclass").value);
                }

                //display route
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        } else {
                //delete route from map
                directionsDisplay.setDirections({ routes: [] });
                //center map in London
                map.setCenter(myLatLng);

                //show error message
                $("#output").html("<div class='alert-danger'>Could not retrieve driving distance.</div>");
        }
        });

    }



    //create autocomplete objects for all inputs
    var options = {
        types: ['(places)']
    }
<div class="row">

                    <form name="airport_booking" method="POST" action="{{action('Spe\AirporttransfersController@store')}}" role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="pickup">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                                <input type="hidden" name="type" >   
                            <div class="form-row">

                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>Full Name</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" required disabled value="{{$summary['fullname']}}"  >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>Telephone</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="tel" id="pickup_telephone" name="Telephone" pattern="^[0-9\ \(\)\+]{13}" class="form-control" disabled style="width:21.5em" value="{{$summary['telephone']}}" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" disabled value="{{$summary['email']}}" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>Arrival</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="pickupdate" onchange="checkDate_arrival()" value="{{$summary['pickupdate']}}" id="arrival"  class="form-control datetimepicker" disabled>
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>Adults</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="adults" id="arrival" value="{{$summary['adults']}}" class="form-control datetimepicker" disabled >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>Children</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="children" value="{{$summary['children']}}"  id="arrival" class="form-control" disabled >
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>Elderly</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="elderly" id="arrival" value="{{$summary['elderly']}}" class="form-control" disabled>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 search-col-padding">
                                   <label>Airline</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="airline" value="{{$summary['airline']}}" class="form-control" disabled >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 search-col-padding">
                                   <label>Flight Number</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="flightnumber" value="{{$summary['flightnumber']}}" class="form-control"  disabled >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>Source</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="carclass" id = "source" value="{{$summary['fromwhere']}}"  id="arrival" class="form-control" disabled>                                                                 
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>Destination</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="destination" id="destination" value="{{$summary['destination']}}" class="form-control" disabled >
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>Car Type/Class</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="carclass" id="carclass" value="{{$summary['carclass']}}" class="form-control" disabled >
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>YOUR PAYMENT METHOD</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="ptmethod"  id="ptmethod" class="form-control" disabled >   
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 search-col-padding">
                                    <label>FARE DETAILS</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">

                                        <input type="text" name="fare" id="fareairport" disabled class="form-control" >
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                                <i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="fromwhere" value="EBB INT AIRPORT">
                                <div class="col-md-12 search-col-padding">
                                    <input type="submit" name="airport_pickup_submit" class="btn btn-theme md-btn text-uppercase mt-2" value="Book">
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
            </div>
```

> This is the javascript script which calculates the the distance, time and sets the value of an input(total price) in the form. The script returns the distance and time but it does not set the price according to the "if loop" it returns the else part
>   the id fairairport is the id of the price input that is set if a distance is within a certain and depends also on the class of the car chosen.

Comment: Please show the html that you are using

Comment: i have added the html which is a laravel blade template

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the if else in your use case, you can use [Switch Statement in Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp). It will be more efficient and easier to debug.

For your use case, you can create 2 switch statement: 1 for the car class and 1 for the distance. Here is a [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/z1h793pL/) that calculates the fare of your trip depending on the distance from your source and destination. I base some of the values in your code.

Below is the part where I used a Switch Statement for the distance inside a Switch Statement for the car class.

```
 switch (activities.value) {
            case "1":

                switch (true) {
                    case (distance <= 20):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "30000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 21) && (distance <= 30):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "70000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 31) && (distance <= 40):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "100000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 41) && (distance <= 50):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "130000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 51) && (distance <= 60):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "160000";
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("More than 60 KM");
                }
                break;
            case "2":
                //Price2
                switch (true) {
                    case (distance <= 20):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "50000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 21) && (distance <= 30):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "100000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 31) && (distance <= 40):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "150000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 41) && (distance <= 50):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 51) && (distance <= 60):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("More than 60 KM");
                }
                break;
            case "3":
                switch (true) {
                    case (distance <= 20):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "50000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 21) && (distance <= 30):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "100000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 31) && (distance <= 40):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "150000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 41) && (distance <= 50):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 51) && (distance <= 60):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    default:
                       alert("More than 60 KM");
                }
                break;
            case "4":
                switch (true) {
                    case (distance <= 20):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "50000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 21) && (distance <= 30):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "100000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 31) && (distance <= 40):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "150000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 41) && (distance <= 50):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 51) && (distance <= 60):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("More than 60 KM");
                }
                break;
            case "5":
                switch (true) {
                    case (distance <= 20):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "50000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 21) && (distance <= 30):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "100000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 31) && (distance <= 40):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "150000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 41) && (distance <= 50):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 51) && (distance <= 60):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("More than 60 KM");
                }
                break;
            case "6":
                switch (true) {
                    case (distance <= 20):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "50000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 21) && (distance <= 30):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "100000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 31) && (distance <= 40):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "150000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 41) && (distance <= 50):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 51) && (distance <= 60):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("More than 60 KM");
                }
                break;
            case "7":
                switch (true) {
                    case (distance <= 20):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "50000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 21) && (distance <= 30):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "100000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 31) && (distance <= 40):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "150000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 41) && (distance <= 50):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    case (distance >= 51) && (distance <= 60):
                        //Price
                        document.getElementById('fare').innerHTML = "200000";
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("More than 60 KM");
                }
                break;
            default:
                alert("default");
        }
    });
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you be so kind to accept the answer? Thank you so much!